# Adjust position of some tool tips based on class of trigger using jqueryTOOLS

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, jquery-tools

I am using the [jqueryTOOLS](http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/index.html) plugin for jquery to generate tooltips for a set of form fields on my site.

The event trigger is dictated by a small piece of javascript:

```
$(function() {
$("#myform :input[title],label[title]").tooltip({
position: "top center",
offset: [-10, 0],
effect: "fade",
opacity: 1.0
      });
    });
```

As you can see, this triggers the title attribute of s and s as a tooltip onFocus.

You can also see that the configuartion of the tooltip takes place as part of this javascript, position is set, as well as an offset etc.

**My problem:**

There is no one position the tooltip can occupy relative to the fields in the form which is suitable. Some elements I need it to appear on the left, some to the right, and some above. I am looking for a way, based on the class of the element, to dictate an alternative position for the element.

**I have tried:**

Setting the class of a element for which I need the tip to appear to the left like so:

```
<input  
        title="This text becomes the tooltip" 
        class="errorleft" 
        type="radio" 
        name="somename" 
        value="value" 
        id="elementID"  
                />
```

and then adjusting my javascript to include an additional trigger:

```
$(function() {
$("#myform :input[title],label[title]").tooltip({
position: "top center",
offset: [-10, 0],
effect: "fade",
opacity: 1.0
      });
    });

    $(function() {
$("#myform.errorleft :input[title],label[title]").tooltip({
position: "center left",
offset: [0, 0],
effect: "fade",
opacity: 1.0
      });
    });
```

This does not work (and I can see why) and I know there is a way to do this, but I can't see a way to it, so far non of the documentation I can find on the jqt website has discussed this.

Any ideas much appreciated

**jsFiddle**
Here is a jsfiddle of my situation using a demo form, and the code I have attempted - in this example the Email field has the class "errorleft" where as all the others are classless. All tooltips display on the right
http://jsfiddle.net/DjHr7/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a space in your selector. As currently written,

```
$("#myform.errorleft :input[title],label[title]")
```

means, find the element that has an id **#myform** AND a class **.errorleft**. It should work with the following syntax:

```
$("#myform .errorleft")
```

This means, find an element with class **.errorleft** inside an element with an id of **#myform**

(You don't have to worry about adding `:input[title],label[title]` if you give each input field a class

Comment: Thanks for this - it doesn't seem to have made a difference though - I created this jsfiddle with this format you suggest, (the Email field in the form is set with a class errorleft, but displays as normal) http://jsfiddle.net/DjHr7/1/ (even with your syntax adjustment)

Comment: check out this fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/tppiotrowski/DjHr7/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/tppiotrowski/DjHr7/3/) you had the right idea, but your selectors still need some work `#myform .errorleft :input` means that you want an input inside an element with class errorleft inside an element with id myform. however, your input element has the errorleft class, so it should be just `#myform .errorleft` or `#myform input.errorleft`

Comment: btw, thanks for posting your fiddle. it makes debugging problems a breeze!

Comment: Fantastic! I've just applied this to my code and works well throughout - no probs with the jsfiddle, it's the least I could do, thanks for taking the time to correct it for me. Thank you!